# FireBase use filter

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, filter

I have got problem with filtering firebase data in js file. Cant use the filter, it just add the new row with data I want to search. Can anybody tell me whats wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
var searchBox = document.getElementById("firstname");
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users").orderByChild('username').equalTo(searchBox.value);
rootRef.on("child_added", snap => {
    var name = snap.child("username").val();
    var secname = snap.child("secondname").val();
    $("#table_body").append("<tr><td style='text-align:left'>" + name 
        + "</td><td style='text-align:left'>" + secname 
        + "</td><td><button id='myButton' onclick='myFunction()'>Remove</button></td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: Can you: 1) edit your question to include the JSON that you query (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data). 2) reproduce the problem with a hardcoded value for `searchBox.value`? 3) reproduce the problem with `console.log`, instead of adding the result to the HTML? Together these steps help you create a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which makes it much more likely that someone will see what's going wrong.

Comment: I did, console gives me needed result, I just can't to show it in table.                                  var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child("Users");
  rootRef.orderByChild('username').equalTo(searchBox.value).on("value",  function(snapshot) {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
  snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
  console.log(data.key);
  });

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link under it) to include all the information. Without all those things, we won't be able to help further.